# How to update Route Table and Security Configuration of Azure Virtual Hub using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have created an Azure Virtual WAN along with Secure Azure Virtual Hub using Terraform scripts. For that I have followed this [documentation](https://github.com/SzkolaDevNet/Terraform-Azure-vWAN).

I want to add the route table configuration to the Azure Virtual Hub using Terraform.
[image: Route table configuration of Azure Virtual Hub]

And then secure the Private Traffic of all virtual connections inside an Azure Virtual Hub Security Configuration using Terraform.

[image: Virtual Hub Security Configuration]

Comment: connectivity between secured hub to hub over azure firewall is not yet supported. To resolve the issue private traffic route configuration will need to be set to Bypass Azure Firewall (Unsecured). For more information please refer this Document: http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/microsoft-azure/microsoft-azure-virtual-wan-part-7-configure-security-configuration---route-traffic-to-your-secured-hub---test-connectivity

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT, If possible provide the sample terraform scripts for securing the private and internet traffic.

Comment: Sure will check and get back you.

Answer (score 1):

There currently doesn't seem to be a way to update the default or none routing tables in a vnet hub as there isn't an API for vhub route table routes as you can see in the [discussion from this feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11169).

Here's what I did:

1. I created a custom vhub route table with the desired routes (I'm using all_traffic) but use whatever.
2. I then added a `routing` block to the vpn connections and vnet  hub connection.

Now when I list the routing tables (`az network vhub route-table list --resource-group <your_group> --vhub-name <vhub name>`) I can see that my new routing table is associated to the `hubVirtualNetworkConnections`

The only downside I've noticed so far is that the UI shows the connections as unsecured, though it seems to be working properly. As mentioned in the documentation, it seems the UI is picky and only reflects correctly using the default route table and the correct route names.

Answer (score 0):

To secure private traffic in a virtual hub connection you can use the following configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_hub_connection" "main" {
  name = "connection-name"

  remote_virtual_network_id = <network id>
  virtual_hub_id            = <virtual hub id>

  routing {
    propagated_route_table {
      route_table_ids = ["${<virtual hub id>}/hubRouteTables/noneRouteTable"]
      labels = ["none"]
    }
  }
}
```

Set the label and route table id, under the routing block, to `none` like shown in the example
above to configure the virtual hub connection to secure private traffic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).